# How can I invoke npm on heroku command line (to install bower components)?

Tags: node.js, heroku, bower

[Bower](http://twitter.github.com/bower/) is for client side Javascript what npm is for the server side and reads a `component.json` file to recognize dependencies that should be fetched at deploy time so I'd be happy it heroku would run it at slug compilation time.

Unfortunately I can not invoke npm or bower from a heroku console or one-off command (`heroku run "npm help"`)  (`heroku run bash` -> `npm help`) as it's possible with ruby's rake. I've put npm and node (latest/x versions) in my `package.json` but in the engines section, not the dependencies.

I think this could be solved by customizing the [node buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs) but I consider this a little too heavy task just for activating something so obvious.

Comment: To the answers below: what if you want to see if your buildpack can safely npm install a package that has binary dependencies. Adding a package.json dependency requires a `git push heroku` to test, whereas a `heroku run npm install ....` to test, not affecting your production. I still have yet to figure out how to run npm with `heroku run bash`

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can also setup a `postintall` command, something like this in your `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
    "bower": "0.6.x"
},
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install"
}
```

Then `npm install` will also install bower dependencies.

*Pros* : one command to rule them all.

*Cons* : you unnecessarily embed bower as a dependency.

Comment: Great solution nontheless, I didn't know about that postinstall script. Need to dig more into npm docs...

Comment: to install dependency for latest bower, execute: `npm install --save bower`

Comment: Awesome! Didn't think about that solution.

Comment: If you want it to work on Windows too you need to prefix the command with node: `node ./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install`

Comment: At least nowadays there should be no need to include the `./node_modules/bower/bin/` bit, as npm will include it in the PATH while running a script defined in package.json.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `run` like this:

```
heroku run npm install git://github.com/webjay/kaiseki
```

Comment: well that's only invoking npm (actually the headline was a little misleading) -> the question is mostly about installing bower dependencies after installation. I only took npm as example. Your command line would invoke npm correctly but I may not forget to call it manually -> the solution from xavier.seignard does everything automatically at deploy time.

Comment: This is very useless. This creates a temporary dyno, runs the command and then destroys it. Your real dynos will be unaffected.

Answer (score 5):

[You should declare NPM dependencies in the package.json file](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs#declare-dependencies-with-npm)

All you install from shell will be deleted on exit shell. You are in a cloned instance.

Answer (score -1):

You can use bower directly like this

```
"dependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.7.9"
},
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "sudo bower install --allow-root "
}
```