# How to run Bower on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, bower

I'm trying to deploy a NodeJs App on Heroku and this app uses bower.
I did what have been suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736941/how-can-i-invoke-npm-on-heroku-command-line-to-install-bower-components), but I'm having this error on Heroku after a push:

bower error status code of git: 128

Answer (score 6):

Here is what I use in my app:

### Adding proper scripts to `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node web.js",
  "postinstall": "bower cache clean && bower install"
},
```

### Add `bower` to dependency list

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "bower": "~1.3.12",
   ...
},
```

### Publishing flow for `Heroku` is following

1. It pulls recent version
2. Runs `install`
3. Runs `postinstall`
4. Runs `start`

### My Sample

- https://github.com/gevorg/typeitquick/blob/master/package.json

Answer (score 2):

Well, doing that may not fix this problem, but you can use

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

to tell git to use HTTPS instead of GIT which worked out for me to install npm dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently people have cleaned their cache?

https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/50

You can run arbitrary commands on your heroku host by using:

```
heroku run console
```

Comment: Good to know @Aurélien. I ended pushing all my /bower_components directory to git and it worked.

Comment: If it works :) Hope you will be able to use bower properly at some point!

Comment: @RodrigoReis pushing bower components is bad idea, just follow few steps  that I described.