# Can't run bower install on heroku

Tags: heroku, bower

I tried following the answer to this question:

[How can I invoke npm on heroku command line (to install bower components)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736941/how-can-i-invoke-npm-on-heroku-command-line-to-install-bower-components)

But keep getting this error in the heroku logs:

```
7763 info TEAMVEGA@0.0.1 Failed to exec postinstall script
7764 error TEAMVEGA@0.0.1 postinstall: `./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install`
7764 error Exit status 8
7765 error Failed at the TEAMVEGA@0.0.1 postinstall script.
7765 error This is most likely a problem with the TEAMVEGA package,
7765 error not with npm itself.
7765 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
7765 error     ./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install
```

Heroku can't seem to find the bower command. I'm not sure why bower isn't getting installed even though it's in my package.json.

Comment: Can you copy your package.json over, and the complete error that bower returns when installing?

Comment: The error info can be misleading, I got it after a dozen of packages got installed... check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31535799/2650732
Hope it helps.