# errors deploying to heroku

Tags: heroku, npm, bower-install

I am getting a series of error when I try to push to heroku master.

```
    remote:  npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    remote:        npm ERR!     bower install
```

The docs https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support showed me how to add bower

Here is my package.json. I am not sure what I could be missing.  I have my engine and npm identified.

```
{
  "name": "caffeine",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bower install",
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.12.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.4",
    "debug": "~2.1.1",
    "express": "~4.12.2",
    "express-session": "^1.11.3",
    "jade": "~1.9.2",
    "moment": "^2.10.3",
    "mongoose": "^4.0.2",
    "morgan": "~1.5.1",
    "node-phantom-simple": "^1.2.0",
    "passport": "^0.2.2",
    "passport-facebook": "^2.0.0",
    "passport-google-oauth": "^0.2.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-local-mongoose": "^1.0.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.2.0",
    "should": "^6.0.3",
    "swig": "^1.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-jshint": "^1.11.0",
    "gulp-nodemon": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.29",
    "npm": "2.1.11"
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks to be an issue with your heroku + bower set up.  Can you verify that bower is installed as expected on `heroku`.  Also, looks like your link is leading to a generic help page.  [Here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys) is a page that you might find helpful.  Are there any more verbose error logs?  Those 2 lines don't tell us a whole lot.

Comment: I set up bower in my package.json last night.  Which bower gives me the user path that I need.  I am getting more errors out of this though.   When I add heroku open I get:  at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico.   This could be many things so I am trying to refactor everything as I do not know what this  is.

Comment: Well the favicon problem can be fixed by adding a route in express to catch any unmatched paths and return a 404 error.

Comment: Your get "App crashed" most likely because "bower install" failed and you lack "bower_components" directory with all its goodies. Of course there could be some other reason as well.

Answer (score 0):

First try to determine if the problem is at Heroku or locally with your packages/bower setup. Try this:

Remove your **bower_components** directory and then run `bower install`. When I did this angular needed help with resolving its version. I chose one of the alternatives, prefixed it with a "**!**" which added this to my **bower.json:**

```
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "~1.3.8"
  }
```

Then depolyed and the postinstall worked. The bottom line is that **bower install** should recreate the deleted **bower_components** without any fuzz locally, before you tell Heroku to run it.